# Calling on fake data within the sql query

Tags: python, sql, database

I am calling on fake data within the sql query that I am using in place of tables untill I get access so I can move on with my dev. I am trying to call on this data from python but every library I see seems to need to connect to a database and have a defined object for this connection. Since all my fake data is in the query, I am unsure what to do as far as calling that sql query in python without that object, what do I need to do to make that work.
Also I am pretty new to sql so may be misunderstanding something here. Thank you.

Here is the fake sql data:

```
WITH 
    fake_data
as
    (SELECT
        f1.username,
        f1.date,
        f1.date1,
        f1.num,
        f1.num1,
        f1.num2,
    FROM
        (VALUES
            ('user.name1','06/15/20','07/2/20','298','0.17446838','0.2541086'),
            ('user.name2','05/5/19','03/4/20','1401','0.305338','0.40653'),
            ('user.name3','10/24/16','12/3/18','350','0.09938','0.1463432'),
        ) f1 (username,date,date1,num,num1,num2)
    ORDER BY
        f1.username asc
    )
SELECT
    f1.username as username,
    f1.date as date,
    f1.date1 as date1,
    f1.num as num,
    f1.num1 as num1,
    f1.num2 as num2
```

Comment: No FROM clause?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? date is a SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), either delimit as `"date"`, or change to something else.

Comment: For development purposes there are plenty of free database engines you can install or run locally minutes. For example, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle. SQL Server, Sybase, H2, Derby, etc. Heck you can even run DB2 in a docker container. There's no reason to develop a complicated, error prone, untested replacement.